# concatenation with random strings

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

So I'm trying to make a simple dice rolling program which I am going to use in a future project however I ran into some problems. I want to be able to pick 2 random numbers and then put those numbers into a sentence in the text box. Of course I realized that I couldn't concatenate integers with strings so at first I tried converting the ints to strings but that didn't work. So now I have this:

```
    Random r1 = new Random();
    Random r2 = new Random();
    int dice1Number;
    int dice2Number;
    string dice1Text;
    string dice2Text;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var r1 = new Random();
        dice1Number = r1.Next(1, 6);
        var r2 = new Random();
        dice2Number = r2.Next(1, 6);
        if (dice1Number == 1)
        {
            dice1Text = "1";
        }
        else if (dice1Number == 1)
        {
            dice1Text = "2";
        }
        else if (dice1Number == 1)
        {
            dice1Text = "3";
        }
        else if (dice1Number == 1)
        {
            dice1Text = "4";
        }
        else if (dice1Number == 1)
        {
            dice1Text = "5";
        }
        else if (dice1Number == 1)
        {
            dice1Text = "6";
        }

        if (dice2Number == 1)
        {
            dice2Text = "1";
        }
        else if (dice2Number == 1)
        {
            dice2Text = "2";
        }
        else if (dice2Number == 1)
        {
            dice2Text = "3";
        }
        else if (dice2Number == 1)
        {
            dice2Text = "4";
        }
        else if (dice2Number == 1)
        {
            dice2Text = "5";
        }
        else if (dice2Number == 1)
        {
            dice2Text = "6";
        }
        textBox1.Text = "You rolled " + dice1Text ", " + dice2Text;
    }
```

I thought this method might work better but now I'm getting an error that says "only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement". Any idea how I could fix this or another way I could make this work?

Comment: On which line this error occur ?

Comment: `string.Join()` method ? along with `string.Format()`

Comment: You have a bunch of `else if (diceXNumber == 1)`. I'm guessing this is a typo and you mean to check 1 through 6. But simply, `dice1Number.ToString()` is just fine, or `String.Format("You rolled {0}, {1}", dice1Number, dice2Number);`

Comment: Did you ever try using `ToString` on the numbers?

Comment: You don't need two instances of `Random`. You should absolutely *not* create a new instance of `Random` on every button click.

Comment: The upper bound on the next function is exclusive.  you are get numbers between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string.Format("You rolled {0},{1}", dice1Number, dice2Number);
```

With that you don't need the big `if` block.  You can also convert an `int` to a string like this:

```
dice1Number.ToString();
```

That will convert it to a string.

On an unrelated note - you have a global `Random` r1 but then redeclare it in your method.  You should just reuse the Random object without declaring a new one for each random number you want to generate.

To clean up this code (assumption being made that you don't need to store the dice roll, just want to display what was rolled) you could change your button click code like this:

```
private Random _rand = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Format("You rolled {0}, {1}", _rand.Next(1,7), _rand.Next(1,7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate integer and string like this.

```
String test = String.Concat("something", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do want you want.

```
    var rnd = new Random();
    var d1 = rnd.Next(1, 7), d2 = rnd.Next(1, 7);

    String.Concat("You rolled ", String.Join(", ", d1.ToString(), d2.ToString()));
```

keep in mind that the upper bound is exclusive.